# Windows 10 won't shutdown

Tags: windows-10, shutdown

I upgraded to Windows 10 a month ago, and since then I have not been able to shutdown(or restart) my computer other than holding the power button.

Choosing Shutdown or restart from the menu does nothing ( doesn't close any programs )

Running `shutdown -r -t 0`    ( or any shutdown command from the command line ) results in a "procedure not found" error message. (I checked that it exists in the system32 folder)

Steps taken:

- made sure "fast boot" is turned off
- made sure power buttons are set to shutdown
- re-created my power settings profile
- ran `sfc /scannow` and found a few corruptions
- ran `chkdsk` and it came back with no errors
- ran Windows updates but it is stuck at Update Home 1511 because it can't restart.

  - I ran Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth  After completing 20% I received the error: "The remote procedure call failed"
  - I uninstalled Toshiba Eco Smart utility, and confirmed there are no updates through Toshiba.

I have a Toshiba satellite Windows 10 x64.

Comment: Is there anything interesting in the Event Logs? [What information appears in event logs? (Event Viewer)](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-information-event-logs-event-viewer#1TC=windows-7)

Comment: Only last week I had an issue on a new Windows 10 Install where 'Settings' Was completely missing! I couldn't change the settings at all. After a hard reboot this fixed my issue.

Comment: The event logs are filled with errors regarding the windows update that failed. Nothing else of consequence. Its like the computer isn't even sending the shutdown command.

Answer (score 0):

This 'Procedure not found' clearly shows that there is something wrong in the core system. Try to run in cmd `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`, with admin privileges of course.

If the DISM doesn't help, you can find clues looking into the Event Logger, and see if there is any error or warning triggered around the time you tried to shutdown your computer, it may give you the answer about what application is causing it, if there is any.

Also, you can try to find an energy manager drivers on the Device Manager and reinstall them.

If nothing helps, I guess you should reinstall Windows, going to Settings > Update & Security > Recovery > Reset this PC > Get Started. You can choose to keep all your files but all your software installed will be removed.

Comment: Most of this answer seems like a comment.  The rest of the answer does not address the author's specific question.  As for what that question is specifically, the author wants to know, how to allow his machine to shutdown cleanly.  Making a statement that says "Upgrading to Windows 10 can cause problems" isn't an answer.

Comment: I'll try the DSM command tonight, thanks. I ran 
Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth and got an error message, but forget exactly what it was. I'll post back later tonight with the results.

Comment: Thanks for the warning, I stripped that away. As for the answer, well, in able to do that we have to try to identify the problem. I suggested some ways the author can try to find and correct that problem and a final alternative if nothing helps. Didn't understand why it doesn't address to the question.

Comment: If I go the "reinstall PC" route, would that be a downgrade back to Windows 8?  Or would it "reinstall" windows 10?

Comment: No. It will reinstall your current Windows installation, unless you choose the 'Go back to Windows 8' option in the Recovery section, if it is still available.

Comment: I ran Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth  After completing 20% I received the error: "The remote procedure call failed"  I uninstalled Toshiba Eco Smart utility, and confirmed there are no updates through Toshiba.  I'll update my original post with these steps. Any further suggestions, or am I stuck re-installing?

Comment: Do Windows + R, type SERVICES.MSC and search for 'Remote Procedure Call', click twice on it (or right click and select properties) and its status should be started/running and the Startup type set to 'Automatic'.
Also, see if the Remote Procedure Call Locator, right under the first one, see if the Startup type is set to 'Manual'.